# Get row number from stream to perform concat

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

Can we simply extract the row number from stream in Pentaho Spoon to perform a concat operation with it, for example?

Let's consider we have:

| # | Country | RowNum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FR | null |
| 2 | BE | null |

Here I want to extract the  **'#'** column value, store it to the **RowNum** column to perform a concatenation. Another solution if it's possible, would be to extract the Row number directly in a **Modified JavaScript value** step to perform the concat operation.

The concat operation is : `Country + str(RowNum)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a step named "Add Sequence" within a transformation which allows for this:

[image]

It will add per row a unique id. If you set it to start with 1 and to add 1 for each consecutive value, it will act as a rownumber.